# Pandas compute datetime diff, but for each user

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by, pandas-groupby

Dataset is related to time user spent on viewing items:

```
user_id   item_id           view_started
  121        160       2015-10-20 17:02:02
  231        160       2015-10-18 11:02:29
  231        161       2015-10-18 11:05:23
  121        166       2015-10-18 11:04:34
  231        180       2015-10-18 11:06:16
  121        182       2015-10-20 17:02:10
  134        182       2015-10-18 11:02:53
  124        185       2015-10-18 11:04:23
  231        187       2015-10-18 11:04:45
  124        190       2015-10-18 11:05:43
```

The goal is to create time spent viewing (or Gap Between Viewing Item) item by the user per item.

```
user_id item_id     minutes
  121     160        4320
  ...
```

The difference should get calculated between the immediate item that user has viewed. Example: `X1, X2, X3 | Time between X1-X2, X2-X3...` and for each group time needs to be reset. I believe using `diff` is not the right approach.

```
df.groupby(['user_id']).apply(
            lambda x: x.sort_values(['view_started'], ascending = True))['view_started'].diff()
```

This gives the first value `NaT`. Time difference should get reset per group (per user)

```
* Time probably don't reflect the above data frame due to sort

0                  NaT
1      0 days 00:08:58
2      0 days 00:04:51
3      0 days 00:06:46
4      0 days 17:05:03
5      0 days 00:00:51
6    -9 days +10:21:49
7      0 days 00:02:33
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`diff` seems fine here, but you will need to do a bit of housekeeping. First, sort your data:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['user_id', 'view_started']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Now, you can perform a `groupby` + `diff` operation.

```
df['minutes'] = (
    df.groupby('user_id', sort=False)
      .view_started
      .diff()
      .dt.total_seconds()
      .div(60)
      .shift(-1)
)
```

```
df
   user_id  item_id        view_started      minutes
0      121      166 2015-10-18 11:04:34  3237.466667
1      121      160 2015-10-20 17:02:02     0.133333
2      121      182 2015-10-20 17:02:10          NaN
3      124      185 2015-10-18 11:04:23     1.333333
4      124      190 2015-10-18 11:05:43          NaN
5      134      182 2015-10-18 11:02:53          NaN
6      231      160 2015-10-18 11:02:29     2.266667
7      231      187 2015-10-18 11:04:45     0.633333
8      231      161 2015-10-18 11:05:23     0.883333
9      231      180 2015-10-18 11:06:16          NaN
```

Comment: @COLDSPEED what is `shift(-1)` job here? any recommendations for NaN, replace with Avg per user?.

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis The minutes watched should be associated with the entry just above where it is actually generated, so I shift it up. For example, X -> Y will initially generate NaN, xyz mins, even though xyz is associated with the X item, not Y. As for NaNs, you may consider filling with the average, something like `df.minutes = df.minutes.fillna(df.groupby('user_id').minutes.transform('mean'))`. You can also use sklearn's imputer, but that cannot handle group-wise fill operations.